# how to draw the phase portrait of the system when the eigenvalues are 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=x(x-y) \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}=y(2x-y)$$

I know that

1. A fixed point is $(0,0)$.
2. The Jacobian is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2x-y & -x \\
2y & 2x-2y
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

We can find when the Jacobian becomes

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

so that the eigenvalues become $0$ as well.

However, I do not know how to draw the phase portrait.